# Make a script in python that lists adjacent words through Unix?

Tags: python, line

How can I write a script in python through nested dictionaries that takes a `txt` file written as,

```
white,black,green,purple,lavendar:1

red,black,white,silver:3

black,white,magenta,scarlet:4
```

and make it print for each entry before the **:** character,  all neighbors it showed up next to

```
white: black silver magenta

black: white green red 

green: black purple
```

and so on

Edit: Well, I didn't post what I have because it is rather unsubstantial...I'll update it if I figure out anything else... I just have been stuck for a while - 
all I have figured out how to do is post each word/letter on a separate line with:

```
from sys import argv
script,filename=argv
txt=open(filename)
for line in txt:
    line=line[0:line.index(';')]
    for word in line.split(","):
        print word
```

I guess what I want is to have some kind of for loop that runs through each word, if the word is not in an original dictionary, I'll add it to it, then I'll search through for words that appear next to it in the file.

Comment: If you are looking only for a `python` solution, this would be better on Stack Overflow. If you are looking for a solution using specific Linux/Unix tools, then please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/118654/edit) and say so! Your requirements are also unclear, please explain more.

Comment: Show the code you've tried

Comment: What did you achieve so far? Copy the code, errors, etc

Comment: Agreed with previous comment. You _may_ accidentally run across someone here who knows enough about python to answer your question, but you'll likely have better luck on Stack Overflow since that's where the programmers hang out. We're more about systems administration here.

Comment: After 10 minutes of hard looking, I understood what you actually mean in the question. Instead of someone else editing, it would be better if you edit the question or else there is a high probability that it might get closed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any algos to read?

Comment: @AaronHall I realized, though, that I need a nested dictionary... so I would need a dictionary having:

{"white":{"black": 1,"silver": 1,"magenta": 1}, "black":{"white": 1, "green": 1, "red":2}...etc. 

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

**Input**

```
a,c,f,g,hi,lw:1

f,g,j,ew,f,h,a,w:3

fd,s,f,g,s:4
```

**Code**

```py
neighbours = {}

for line in file('4-input.txt'):
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue    # skip empty input lines

    line = line[:line.index(':')]   # take everything left of ':'

    previous_token = ''
    for token in line.split(','):
        if previous_token:
            neighbours.setdefault(previous_token, []).append(token)
            neighbours.setdefault(token, []).append(previous_token)
        previous_token = token

    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(neighbours)
```

**Output**

```py
{'a': ['c', 'h', 'w'],
'c': ['a', 'f'],
'ew': ['j', 'f'],
'f': ['c', 'g', 'g', 'ew', 'h', 's', 'g'],
'fd': ['s'],
'g': ['f', 'hi', 'f', 'j', 'f', 's'],
'h': ['f', 'a'],
'hi': ['g', 'lw'],
'j': ['g', 'ew'],
'lw': ['hi'],
's': ['fd', 'f', 'g'],
'w': ['a']}
```

Tidying up the prettyprinted dictionary is left as an exercise for the reader. (Because dictionaries are inherently not sorted into any order, and removing the duplicates without changing the ordering of the lists is also annoying).

Easy solution:

```py
for word, neighbour_list in neighbours.items():
    print word, ':', ', '.join(set(neighbour_list))
```

But that does change the ordering.

Comment: Oh wait, *nested dictionaries*? Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
from collections import defaultdict

char_map = defaultdict(set)
with open('input', 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        a_list, _ = line.split(':') # Discard the stuff after the :
        chars = a_list.split(',') # Get the elements before : as a list
        prev_char = ""
        for char, next_char in zip(chars, chars[1:]): # For every character add the 
                                                      # next and previous chars to the 
                                                      # dictionary
            char_map[char].add(next_char)
            if prev_char:
                char_map[char].add(prev_char)
            prev_char = char

print char_map
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse (input_file):
char_neighbours = {}
File = open(input_file,'rb')
for line in File:
    line = line.strip().split(':')[0]
    if line != "":
        csv_list=line.split(',')
        for i in xrange(0,len(csv_list)-1):
            value = char_neighbours.get(csv_list[i]) or False
            if value is False:
                char_neighbours[csv_list[i]] = []
            if(i<len(csv_list)):
                if str(csv_list[i+1]) not in char_neighbours[str(csv_list[i])]:
                    char_neighbours[str(csv_list[i])].append(str(csv_list[i+1]))
            if(i>0):
                if str(csv_list[i-1]) not in char_neighbours[str(csv_list[i])]:
                    char_neighbours[str(csv_list[i])].append(str(csv_list[i-1]))
return char_neighbours

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dictionary=parse('test.txt')
    print dictionary
```

the parse method returns a dictionary of strings with a list of neighbours as their values

Comment: This is not going to fly with any Python interpreter/compiler due to indentation issues

Comment: Stackoverflow indented it this way when I pasted it. You can just select the code below the function and press tab to indent it